# I can't move to the next round!

Tags: windows, need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005

I'm playing Need For Speed: Most Wanted, I need to press `Enter` to move to the next round. It doesn't seem to be working even though it works fine on other games and programs.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why the vote-down?

Comment: You're not really giving us much to go on that you can't just accomplish by googling "NFS Most Wanted Enter key not working"

Comment: @Shykin I already did that but I couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue.

However to help you Adegoke, to get past races I've had to go to the store and then escape, since it allows you to hit enter to continue or control+R to go to store. That being said if you get a prompt regarding limited edition I have yet to find a way to get the enter key to work, however I'm sure if you attach a controller (Which I recommend for the game) it may let you past it.